# What does Refrigeration have to do with Submarines?

Tags: civilization-5

I noticed in the Civ 5 tech tree that you can build submarines once you finish researching Refrigeration. I honestly don't get the connection. Why are submarines dependent on refrigeration? Is there a historical reason for this?

Link to [Civ 5 Tech tree](http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_technologies.html) (pre-expansion)

Comment: Sometimes a game is just a game. Meaning that there is no deeper secret to it.

Comment: I figure refrigeration is necessary for food aboard ship. There's no room for barrels and barrels of salt pork.

Comment: @None That doesn't mean one shouldn't settle one's curiosity by asking if there happens to be a reason behind something.

Comment: @Ender True, but I wonder if this question is fit for Arqade. Even though it is based on something encountered in a game, it is not really a gaming question.

Comment: This is obviously a "why did they design it that way" question, which is not a good fit for Arqade.

Comment: This may be on-topic over on http://history.stackexchange.com, but this has little to do with gaming.

Comment: I have the feeling that history.stackexchange would have noted this as off topic and sent me here

Comment: There is absolutely no connection between submarines and refrigeration. Refrigeration is directly connected to super markets and a massive improvement of productivity of industrialized and healthy citizens, but zero connection to submarines. Making it the requirement for subs was merely a "TV logical" rationalization to spread out the naval units. Diesel engines was all that was needed for effective submarines, although sonar was a great boon for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case of submarines, refrigeration is somewhat tangentially linked.  While one of the issues with a submarine is temperature, most of the time the problem is that the sub is too cold - not too hot.  The ocean is quite a cold place, on the whole, with the average temperature in the single digits in degrees Celsius.

Similarly, feeding the people on a submarine could be accomplished without refrigeration as well.  Even some modern army rations don't require it.

However, [gas compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_compressor), one of the foundations of modern refrigeration, is important to submarines.  Compressed air is used to adjust the buoyancy of the sub by displacing water in the ballast tanks.

Having said all that, it's a bit tough to look at the tech tree for any Civ game and attempt to directly link units to the technology that unlocks them - in many cases, there are clear links, but not always.  For instance, what do pikemen have to do with Civil Service?  Or why do paratroopers depend on Radar?  Not all helicopters depend on Rocketry, either.

It's usually sufficient to say "these military units were roughly coincident in time with the given technology."  In the case of refrigeration and submarines, both rose to prominence during World War I, in the mid-to-late 1910's.

Comment: You sir, know entirely too much, about entirely too much. Go stick your head in a hole somewhere, for the good of the rest of us.

Comment: Thanks for noting that multiple technologies are incongruous with which units they unlock.

Comment: Diesel subs were hot, cramped environments. Not sure about modern nuclear subs because they use some of their excessive power for air-conditioning.